# jQuery .html() Outputs html code as text not html

Tags: jquery, html, razor

I have this issue where i build a string which I know is legit(Checked it out individually), but when I send it as a parameter to my jQuery function the .html() function still outputs it as a string! I'm using Razor VB as my server side language.

**This is the output:**

```
<table><tr><th>Cause</th><th>Delay</th></tr></table>
```

**The String builder:**

```
Dim obstacleList As String

obstacleList = "<table><tr><th>Orsak</th><th>Försening</th></tr>"

For Each obstRow In obstData

   obstacleList = obstacleList & "<tr><td>" & obstRow.cause & "</td><td>" & obstRow.hoursplaned & "</td></tr>"

Next

   obstacleList = obstacleList & "</table>"
```

**The code where I put the variables in:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">popup("@obstacleList" , @row.id);</script>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
function popup($dbData, $rowid) {
   $('<div class="tooltip' + $rowid + '"></div>').fadeIn("fast").appendTo('body');
   $('.tooltip' + $rowid + '').html($dbData);
}
```

Comment: Do you not need some further markup in your HTML string to tell the browser that this is HTML? i.e. <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> etc?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Read the generated source.

Comment: But wait, what are you looking for as html() returns string as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, apparently you need to specify in the outgoing parameters that the razor-vb string is to be used as raw html data. Otherwise both of your solutions worked!

`<script type="text/javascript">popup("@(html.Raw(obstacleList))" , @row.id);</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('.tooltip' + $rowid + '').append($dbData);
```

instead of

```
$('.tooltip' + $rowid + '').html().
```

or

```
$('.tooltop' + $rowid + '').html(function(index, yourOldHtml) {
    return $dbData;
}
```

if `$dbData` is your `<table><tr><th>Cause</th><th>Delay</th></tr></table>` string.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qhm5D/)

**update**

as @roasted pointed out, the `append()` way isn't the exact same behaviour as `html()` as it empties the element first. use `.empty().append($dbData)`. Thanks roasted!

Comment: BTW, append() is not the same behaviour, maybe .empty().append() then

Comment: Still not getting any html output, just the text string which includes all the html tags. (I am including the code into a document with other html tags btw, so it can't be that.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing your problem, but there is no need to select the div you just created (you already have it in memory) - you can just chain the commands;

```js
function popup(dbData, rowid) {
   $('<div class="tooltip' + rowid + '"></div>') // create a div
        .html(dbData) // first insert html
        .appendTo('body') // before attaching to DOM
        .fadeIn('fast'); // and fading in
}
```

I also took the liberty of removing the dollar sign from the variable names as they are;

1. Not needed
2. A common naming convention for variables containing a jQuery collection (which neither of these are)

Comment: Didn't know about the naming thing! Thanks for your help!